Longhorn/NFS instability with heavy read/write app, looking for alternatives
I'm using Longhorn with NFS in order to handle RWX on volumes that span multiple nodes in the same datacenter. For some context this is to run video game servers that are dynamically started/stopped.
The server data are all stored in the same RWX volume under a single directory separated by server ID like so:
root:
- {uuid}
- {uuid}
- {uuid}
- {uuid}

The problem we're experiencing is degraded performance when one or more servers are writing a lot of data. This occasionally causes all pods that are mounted on the volume to die presumably because the NFS server can't handle the load and restarts.
Ideally I'd like to store these customer data on the host they're running on in order to avoid the data latency of communicating over a network but because we're autoscaling the underlying nodes up & down to account for demand I'm not sure this is possible without copying the data to the new node before the server starts. Customer servers can be 50GB of data max which could take a while to copy every time the customer wanted to start their server.
Ultimately my main goals for moving away from NFS are:

Improved read/write speed for clients using their servers
No single point of failure. NFS going down and causing all pods mounted to the volume to fail is unacceptable
Having the customer data being stored on the node they're running on would be ideal but I'm not sure this is possible due to the time it would take to copy it back and forth

I've heard Rook+CephFS could be a good alternative for this use case but I'm wary of investing a ton of time migrating to a new technology without confidence that it would significantly improve performance.
